# I can't access nano /etc/bind/named.conf.options, it is blank inside

Tags: dns, bind

I can access `/etc/bind/named.conf/options` on my ubuntu server virtual machine, it should show

```
acl "trusted" {
    10.128.10.11;    # ns1 - can be set to localhost
    10.128.20.12;    # ns2
    10.128.100.101;  # host1
    10.128.200.102;  # host2
};

options {

    . . .
```

but in my case it did not show anything, just blank. What should I do??

Comment: Did you run it with `sudo`? That file would be owned by root.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not supposed to be `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`? I doubt `/etc/bind/named.conf` is a directory. See for example [How To Configure Bind as a Caching or Forwarding DNS Server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)